# Set a static value in restkit mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit

How cant I set a static value while mapping entities?

I have a JSON response like this:

```
"friends": [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Friend",
    },
]
"featured": [
    {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "Some Featured user",
    },
]
```

My mapping and descriptors look like this:

```
RKMapping *friendsMapping = [ProjectMappingProvider userMapping];
RKMapping *featuredMapping = [ProjectMappingProvider featuredUserMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *friendsResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:friendsMapping
        method:RKRequestMethodGET
        pathPattern:@"/api/users"
        keyPath:@"friends"
        statusCodes:statusCodeSet];

RKResponseDescriptor *featuredResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:friendsMapping
        method:RKRequestMethodGET
        pathPattern:@"/api/users"
        keyPath:@"featured"
        statusCodes:statusCodeSet];

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
        responseDescriptors:@[
        friendsResponseDescriptor,
        featuredResponseDescriptor]];

... some code emited for readabilty ...
```

Now mu friendsResponseDescriptor and featuredResponseDescriptors look almost identical, but I would like to set additional CoreData parameter accordingly. Objects mapped through friendsDescriptor should have section = 0 and objects mapped through featured descriptor should have section = 10.

So, can I do something like this?

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:[[DataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id": @"userId",
                                              @"name": @"name"                                                  }];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];

// How can I do somethning like this?
[mapping setValue:@0 forKey:@"section"];
```

And the featured mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:[[DataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id": @"userId",
                                              @"name": @"name"                                                  }];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];

// How can I do somethning like this?
[mapping setValue:@10 forKey:@"section"];
```

Note that I don't have any other indicator whetever user is a friend or featured in the user  JSON itself. The only way I can distinguish the type of user (friend,featured) is in which list in JSON response the user is set.
I am later using the section property in the table view controller to have sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different entities, set default values on them. If you aren't using different entities, consider changing so that you are (they could be sub-entities of a common parent).

You can't insert data into the mapping. The mapping only describes what RestKit should process. To edit the values you would need to get involved in the mapping process yourself and implement some delegate methods to inject additional data.

Comment: Could you explain more on that? Implementing delegate methods to inject additional data. Which methods specifically in Reskit would do that. Some example would be perfect.

Comment: I don't have an example, I've never wanted to get involved at that level. You would need to run the mapping operation yourself. Better (certainly easier) would be different entities with default values...